# How to read a simple json file in keen js

Tags: javascript, json, keen-io

I have a couple of basic local json files. I want to visualize the json data using keen.io. But somehow I cannot send my events to keen. There are no errors in the console.

```
var client = new Keen({
    projectId: "key",
    writeKey: "key"
  });



var data = $.getJSON( "data/web_stories.json", function( data ) {
  var storyData = data
  Keen.ready(function(){
          var multipleEvents = {
                "stories": data
};
// Send multiple events to several collections
client.addEvents(multipleEvents, function(err, res){
  if (err) {
    console.log('there is an error!')
  }
  else {
    console.log('data sent')
  }
```

The data looks like this

```
[
{ link: "www.link.com",
  heading: 'here is the heading',
  image: "www.image.com" },
{ link: "www.link.com",
  heading: 'here is the heading',
  image: "www.image.com" }

]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing `data` defined a few times. How about this:

```
var client = new Keen({
  projectId: "key",
  writeKey: "key"
});

Keen.ready(function(){
  $.getJSON( "data/web_stories.json", function( data ) {
    // Send multiple events to several collections
    client.addEvents({ 'stories': data }, function(err, res){
      if (err) {
        console.log('there is an error!')
      }
      else {
        console.log('data sent')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some syntax errors, try this:

```
var client = new Keen({
    projectId: "key",
    writeKey: "key"
  });

var multipleEvents;

var data = $.getJSON( "data/web_stories.json", function( data ) {
  var storyData = data
  Keen.ready(function(){
          multipleEvents = {
                "stories": data
          };
  });
};
// Send multiple events to several collections
client.addEvents(multipleEvents, function(err, res){
  if (err) {
    console.log('there is an error!')
  }
  else {
    console.log('data sent')
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not solves the problem, It gives me errors from keen it self: addEvents is not a function

Comment: that mean there is something wrong in your Client creation. are you passing the right projectID and writekey?

Comment: Yes the keys are fine but somehow the function is not running. for example when I console.log(storyData) there is nothing in console

Comment: are you sure that your json file is reached with data/web_stories.json ?

it seems like you are reading an empty (or not existing) file..

Comment: You are right there is a problem with reading data however the file lives in the given directory and is not empty